# Send an email with the confirmation MailChimp

Tags: hyperlink, callback, mailchimp

How to send * |EMAIL| * tag or email address in **confirmation "thank you" page** when filled input send subscriber to another url.

> Instead of showing this thank you page, send subscribers to another
>   URL
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/custom_form?*|EMAIL|*
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lists** > select **Signup Forms** from the drop-down menu to the right of the list being worked with> **General forms**, and then click the option at the bottom of the page to "code everything from scratch in **advanced mode**.

Select the **confirmation "thank you" page** and edit the meta tag in the header.
That meta tag will look something like this

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/custom_form?*|EMAIL|*>`

This will tell the browser to refresh and redirect to that URL, as needed.